# javascript capture substring of string using string matching and not indexes

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substr

Hello I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to figure out how to extract a substring from another string.

I know the substring() method captures the string from a starting index to an ending.

But in my case I want to capture a string that starts **after** "val=" all the way to the end of the super-string.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: regular expression `/val=(.*)/` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `indexOf`:

```js
var text = "something val=hello";
var result = text.substr(text.indexOf("val=") + 4);
alert(result);
```

Or use a regex like your tags suggest:

```js
var text = "something val=hello";
var result = /\bval=(.+)/.exec(text)[1];
alert(result);
```

Of course, in both cases you should take care of error cases (for instance, what should happen when `val=` is not in the string).

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "val=hello world";
var idx = str.lastIndexOf('=');
var result = str.substring(idx + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be to read this first: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Then proceed to this: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) / [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```
var identifier = "val=";
var text = "your text val=foo";

var value = text.substring(text.indexOf(identifier) + identifier.length);
```

Or [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), for example using the string's method [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
var text = "your text val=foo";
var matches = text.match(/val=([\s\S]*)/);
var value = matches && matches[1];
```